# Is it possible to reassign created_at key in a PHP associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

// I am pulling product reviews from the database

```
$reviews = $this->Product->get_product_reviews_by_id($info);
```

// then iterating over them, formatting the date and attempting to reassign the created_at key

```
foreach($reviews as $r) {
   $date = explode(" ", $r['created_at']);
   $date = $date[0];
   $time = date_format(date_create($date), "D F d, Y");
   $r['created_at'] = $time;
}
```

// var dumping $time displays the desired date format, however, I have not been able to reassign/attach $time as the new value for display purposes on the front end.  So the main question here is, can I overwrite the initial value of 'created_at' in PHP?

Comment: of course you can.. try dumping the $reviews and you should be able to see the `created_at`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change the value in the reviews array, try this

```
foreach($reviews as $key => $r) {
   $date = explode(" ", $r['created_at']);
   $date = $date[0];
   $time = date_format(date_create($date), "D F d, Y");
   $reviews[$key]['created_at'] = $time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $reviews as $r ) {
    $r [$key]['created_at'] = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A",strtotime($r ['created_at']));
}
```

Adjust the date format how do you want.